# Accessing a C string from fixed Flash location

Tags: c, string

I have define a string at location 0xAABB:

```
const char str[] = "Hi There";  
const word _Str1 @0xAABB = (word)str;
```

Now, I want to access this string located at 0xAABB.
What is the C syntax for this?

Comment: What target processor and compiler?

Comment: In case anyone wants to know that is an 8 bit von Neumann architecture processor.  I was wondering if it was a Harvard architecture.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Just use a pointer to the memory location:

    const char *str = (const char *)0xAABB;</del>

---

**Edit:** (based on your comment) You need to first get the address from location 0xAABB and then use this value as the string's address:

```
const char *str = *(const char **)0xAABB;
```

This will dereference the pointer at 0xAABB to get the actual string address.

Comment: It prints some garbage value. Well, at 0xAABB, there would be some address, lets say 0xAB. So, actual string is lying here, as sen from the definition above.

Comment: const char *str = *(const char **)0xAABB; >>>>> Compiler error: Initializer must be a constant                                   const char *str = const char **)0xAABB;         : Doesn't work.

Comment: To add here, address at 0xAABB is 16 bits and it seems from debugger it is taking only 8 bit adress and hence garbage value string

Comment: @Punit: To resolve that error, just move the initialization to a separate line after the declaration, i.e. `const char *str; str = *(const char **)0xAABB;`

Comment: Well it says, Incompatible type to previous initialization. May be my compiler is dumb enough.

Comment: @Punit: It's possible that your compiler is old, but I don't know how that would give an "incompatible type" error. Are you sure you got the code right? The declaration should be `const char *str` but the assignment should be just `str = ...`, no `*` there.

Comment: Yes, code is correct. Compiler says: found int, expected const unsigned char*

Answer (score 0):

```
#define ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_STRING  ((const char *)0xAABB)

const char *pointer_to_your_string = (const char *)0xAABB;
```

I could have used the macro in the pointer definition, but these are really intended to be separate demonstrations of how to do this.  If you put the macro version in a header file and use it in your code the compiler will be able to optimize a little better.  If you use a global pointer variable to access it then you may end up with the compiler needing to do an extra load of a pointer.

Using both of these is the same:

```
printf("%s\n", ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_STRING);
```

should work just fine since printf expects a pointer to a string for `%s`.